# How to count specific nodes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<color>
   <title>white</title>
</color>
<color>
   <title>black</title>
</color>
<color>
   <title>white</title>
</color>
<color>
   <title>black</title>
</color>
<color>
   <title>white</title>
</color>
```

I need to get the `count` of `color` nodes where `title` equals '`white`' using `xslt`

ie to get the result:  **3**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : `count(color[./title='white'])`

Please try the following code

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="*">
    <Value>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(color[./title='white'])"/>
    </Value>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output : `<Value>3</Value>`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some XSLT to start from, and you'll need valid XML (that only has one root element).

And I would need you to provide both of those in order to give you a full answer, but essentially, you can use the `count()` function and a predicate:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//color[title = 'white'])" />
```

More complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <n>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//color[title = 'white'])"/>
      </n>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```